# I want to add hours to a time field in a PDF Form. Ex, Start Time is 7:00am I want a field to show +2.5 hours from 7:00am as 9:30am. Start time vary

Tags: javascript, time, output, addition

I am a total newbie but am learning a lot about javascript by making this form for my employees. They enter the time they start working on a given day and I want there to be auto-populated fields that give the resulting break times. For example, first break comes at 2.5 hours after start time, lunch is at 5 hours after start time and second break is 7.5 hours after start time.

I've tried looking around but am not finding anything that does what I'm trying to accomplish. Everything seems way more complicated than what I'm looking for.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The workers are entering a time in a text box on a PDF we use as the daily field report. I am working in Adobe Acrobat. I need to make everything dummy proof for them so I want them to see on the form when they need to be taking breaks.